# C++ accessing base class members

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to clarify how inheritance works for a piece of homework.

```
class AA
{
public:
  setAAA();
protected:
  int AAA;
};

class BB : public AA
{
public:
  setBBB();
private:
  int BBB;
};
```

Does the AA inheritance for BB cause BB to have the following member list?
 - AAA
 - BBB
 - setAAA()
 - setBBB()

if It does why can't I perform:

```
BB Frank;
Frank.setAAA();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does mean exactly that and it does work. Run the code here for confirmation:

http://liveworkspace.org/code/51fd6850ebfb5f86dc61c6dc074fe30a

```
#include <iostream>

class AA
{
public:
  void setAAA() { std::cout << "Setting AAA" << std::endl; };
protected:
  int AAA;
};

class BB : public AA
{
public:
  void setBBB() {};
private:
  int BBB;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   BB b;
   b.setAAA();

   return 0;
}
```

Your problem is your methods had no return type :)

Answer (score 3):

> if It does why can't I perform: BB Frank; Frank.setAAA();

Well. Start with defining a return type of `setAAA()`. For instance, make it `void`.

The member function will be accessible then.